# Multiple Tables Search, with Limit Clause and Known Result Source Table Names

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union, sql-limit

A situation arose where I have to heuristically find out a table name from a common id. The tables have the same exact structure so I thought **union** or **union all** will work as suggested by some answers here. The problem is, applying a ***limit clause*** to the query is not working well. If I apply it on *more than one select query*, it fails; if *on one*, it only filters on that table as primary. Even ***wrapping it*** as shown below is not producing the desired result - which is: limit the returned result from each of those individual queries to say one row.

Restating the question: *How can I know if a list of known tables have a particular value (named-column) or not?*

An open option gives good table sources as aliases but multiple limits are prohibited; results could be very many:

```
SELECT `ID`, `BATCH_NUMBER`, 'TBL1' AS 'table_one' FROM `table_one` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
UNION ALL
SELECT `ID`, `BATCH_NUMBER`, 'TBL2' AS 'table_two' FROM `table_two` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
UNION ALL
SELECT `ID`, `BATCH_NUMBER`, 'TBL3' AS 'table_three' FROM `table_three` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123'
```

Wrapped option filters only on the first table results are found; we need all tables with the value.

```
select * from (
SELECT `ID`, `BATCH_NUMBER`, 'TBL1' AS 'table_one' FROM `table_one` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
UNION ALL
SELECT `ID`, `BATCH_NUMBER`, 'TBL2' AS 'table_two' FROM `table_two` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
UNION ALL
SELECT `ID`, `BATCH_NUMBER`, 'TBL3' AS 'table_three' FROM `table_three` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
) as resutl_table  
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer. What result do you want? What does "fails" mean?

Comment: Do you want only the table names that contain the row or full rows from the tables?

Comment: @jarlh; this is my first question and I think the question is already verbose enough. it fails here means MySQL will complain that there is a syntax error near the lines with consecutive limit-by-clauses.

Comment: @forpas, only an array containing the list of tables; table names only.

Comment: this question has been solved by @forpas as shown below; the first option tested and works fine. thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the table names then each of your queries should return only the 1st column:

```
SELECT 'TBL1' AS table_name FROM `table_one` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
UNION
SELECT 'TBL2' AS table_name FROM `table_two` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
UNION
SELECT 'TBL3' AS table_name FROM `table_three` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123'
```

Or, get the results as comma separated string:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) AS table_names
FROM (
  SELECT 'TBL1' AS table_name FROM `table_one` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
  UNION
  SELECT 'TBL2' AS table_name FROM `table_two` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123' 
  UNION
  SELECT 'TBL3' AS table_name FROM `table_three` WHERE `NAMED_ID` = '123'
) t
```

`UNION` will filter out duplicates.

Comment: I have just tested the first option and it works; exactly what I have been searching for for the last 6 hours. thanks a lot.